# Calling autoFocus() from parent Activity returns NPE

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have instantiated a fragment type that extends CameraFragment (and implements TabListener), and I am trying to call the autoFocus() from the the parent Activity. Calling autoFocus() from the fragment that extends CameraFragment works fine, but calling it from the parent Activity results in an NPE. I am listening for a onKeyDown() event in the main Activity, which works as expected as per the logcat. Here is my NPE trace:

```
09-10 10:00:16.410: D/app(5283): onKeyDown: 80

09-10 10:00:16.415: D/AndroidRuntime(5283): Shutting down VM

09-10 10:00:16.415: W/dalvikvm(5283): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f7b2a0)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraFragment.autoFocus(CameraFragment.java:96)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.me.app.appCameraFragment.callAutoFocus(cameraFragment.java:232)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.me.app.MainTabActivity.onKeyDown(MainTabActivity.java:264)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2705)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2423)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2019)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3851)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2934)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)

09-10 10:00:16.425: E/AndroidRuntime(5283):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of the code you are working on, but line 96 is a closing brace in the current `CameraFragment`.

The only way `autoFocus()` can crash with a `NullPointerException` is if `cameraView` is `null`, and the only way `cameraView` should be `null` is if `onCreateView()` has not yet been called. You need the fragment to be visible and fully created before you request auto-focus.

Comment: Which they are, so it's very strange. I think the problem may come from the fact that this fragment is implementing TabListener. On tab selection, the TabListener interface requires the instantiation of the fragment (`mFragment`). When I call `autoFocus()`, I receive an NPE. However, when I call `mFragment.autoFocus()`, the autofocus properly executes. I'm not sure if I am understanding this correctly, but this works for me. Let me know if you can make sense of this.

Comment: @ktal90: Sounds like perhaps you have two instances of the `CameraFragment`, perhaps from a previous tab switch or something.